# Publishing initial state in Observer pattern

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

Is there a preferred idiom for publishing the "initial state" to new observers in the Observer pattern?

Most of the available material and examples describing the Observer pattern assume that observers are interested in being notified of changes, but don't care about the "initial state" (the current state at the time observers subscribe to changes).

One possibility would be to push the "initial" (current) state to new observers when they subscribe, e.g.:

```
public class MyObservable extends java.util.Observable
{
    public synchronized void addObserver(Observer observer)
    {
        super.addObserver(observer);

        // Push current state to this observer
        observer.update(this, currentState);
    }
}
```

Is there a better / preferred approach?

Comment: What stops the observer from asking for current state directly at the moment it registers with the observed?

Comment: Synchronization. In order to avoid a possible race condition between registration and asking for the current state, the observer would need to do both operations atomically (for example, in Java, it would need to synchronize on the same monitor that the observable is using to publish state updates). This adds complexity and exposes the underlying implementation of the observable.

Comment: hmmm, what guarantees that when the observer receives the `update` call the state hasn't been changed? I see that addObserver is `synchronized` but that doesn't mean that access to the state is also synchronized, right?

Comment: This is the responsibility of the observable. If required, the observable can be implemented in such a way that this condition is met, without exposing any implementation details to the observers.

Comment: I understand that, but then the same applies for initial request to the observable state, right? Usually you don't register with Observable, but with the implementation (MyObservable), so you can easily request all the needed info, which would have to be synced anyway. Otherwise, notifying on the registration as you mentioned, seems OK, assuming that currentState somehow carries the info that this is the initial stated for that observer (and not that there has been a change in the state)

ok, I am not sure if i am helping ... :)

Comment: (Discussion always helps) The way I see it, the main difference is that in my approach the required synchronization can be implemented entirely in the observable while with your approach it would need to be implemented by the observer (and would require exposing implementation details of the observable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it can be considered *preferred*,
but in the context of [Reactive Extensions](https://rx.codeplex.com/)' "hot observables", the idiom "[Replay](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#Replay)" is used:

Short demo (C#):

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var observable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Do(l => Console.WriteLine("Publishing {0}", l))  //side effect to show it is running
        .Replay(1);                                       // buffer the last entry

      Console.ReadKey();

      using (observable.Connect())                        // turn it "hot"
      {
        Console.ReadKey();

        observable.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("OnNext #1: {0}", i));

        Console.ReadKey();

        using (observable.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("OnNext #2: {0}", i)))
        {
          Console.ReadKey();
        }                                                 // unsubscribes #2 again

        Console.ReadKey();
      }                                                   // turn it "cold"

      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
     Publishing 0
    Publishing 1
    Publishing 2
     OnNext #1: 2
    Publishing 3
    OnNext #1: 3
    Publishing 4
    OnNext #1: 4
    Publishing 5
    OnNext #1: 5
     OnNext #2: 5
    Publishing 6
    OnNext #1: 6
    OnNext #2: 6
    Publishing 7
    OnNext #1: 7
    OnNext #2: 7
    Publishing 8
    OnNext #1: 8
    OnNext #2: 8
     Publishing 9
    OnNext #1: 9
    Publishing 10
    OnNext #1: 10
```

Comment: You have opened up a whole world that I never knew I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Not really. But usually there's some configuration file or default settings at the root of your observer hierarchy, and so the initial cascade of events will be set off when those are read/set.

The tricky bit is to make sure that all settings are grouped so that the observable entities are set in an order that is "legal", or at least works the way you expect.